# Are there any diagnostics tools for troubleshooting content delivery with Opera Mini?

Tags: ajax, cross-browser, opera-mini

I have an application that I'm targeting a wide variety of devices and platforms. The application can render different HTML based upon the type of client.  However due to the complexity of the application, it shares a considerable amount of JavaScript libraries that rely on a number of async and ajax method calls.

One of the targets for the application is Opera Mini.  This "sort-of" works but it seems like sometimes when building up the specialized markup to send down to the Opera Mini JVM client it does not wait until the async calls are complete.  Are there any techniques or tools to see what's going on with the Opera Server (not my application web server) Side processing of the page to determine what I can do to make this solid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that after further investigation that the server side browser is fairly picky when it comes to CSS.  I can't remember the exact problem, but as soon as I removed the stylesheet all content was displayed properly.  At that point I slowly re-introduced the CSS and everythning came back online and worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript will only be allowed a short time before it is aborted:

> JavaScript running on the Mini server
>   will only run for a couple of seconds
>   before pausing, for resource
>   constraint reasons. This applies to
>   JavaScript run due to an event firing
>   e.g. onload, as well as code run
>   because of a user action.

~ http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-web-content-authoring-guidelines/#javascript

So the best would be to serve the least javascripty version of your site to the Opera Mini user-agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can type `server:source` in the address bar once a page is loaded if you want to see the current DOM tree.

It's also possible to post that source to a script on your server using `server:source?post=http://your.server.com/script.` It will send three fields as a POST request: `url`, `host` and `html`. You can then make your script save it to a file.

(Answering an old question in case it helps someone.)